# Java 8 - Lazy Evaluation?

Tags: java, java-8

I was going through a Streams Video when I found myself confused as to how Streams API was giving lazy evaluation over the imperative for loop approach.

Here's the typical for loop code which checks for the first number that is greater than three and even, it then simply prints it and returns.

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.println(" Checking if is Greater: " + i);
        if (i > 3) {
            System.out.println("checking if is Even " + i);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i * 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the expected output:

```
Checking if is Greater: 1
Checking if is Greater: 2
Checking if is Greater: 3
Checking if is Greater: 5
Checking if is Even 5
Checking if is Greater: 4
Checking if is Even 4
8
```

Now here's the same code using Streams API:

```
arr.stream()
       .filter(Lazy::isGreater)
       .filter(Lazy::isEven)
       .map(Lazy::doubleIt)
       .findFirst();
```

It too evaluates the same way. So how is `filter()` providing something different which we can't get using the traditional for loops?

Comment: Shouldn't your `println` statements be inside their corresponding `if` blocks?

Comment: `filter` doesn't provide something different that you can't get with for loops. It is just a different way of writing code: imperative vs functional.

Comment: Given that Java was turing-complete since its first release, how has anything since then provided something which couldn't be done before?

Comment: You have to distinguish between intermediate and terminal operations. `filter()` is an intermediate operation; all intermediate operations are lazy. But `.forEach()` is a terminal operation and this operation is eager: it will cause the stream pipeline to be evaluated.

Comment: I guess the real question here is, what were you expecting instead?

Comment: @Tunaki Most of the articles I read on Streams API mentioned how beautiful these intermediate operations were and how they added the advantage of being lazy. But it was not mentioned how they provide benefits over the typical imperative mechanisms?

Comment: @Clashsoft I think the sysout messages were a bit misleading. Made them more readable. My intention was to print which if condition is being invoked even if that condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the key: **composability**

```
arr.stream()
       .filter(Lazy::isGreater)
       .filter(Lazy::isEven)
       .map(Lazy::doubleIt)
       .findFirst();
```

That seems innocuous, but this is a value now:

```
 arr.stream()
       .filter(Lazy::isGreater)
```

You can hand it to a method and build on it.

What can do with an equivalent for loop? You can copy-paste it wherever you use it.  It's not a composable abstraction.

Moreover, the Stream makes the **how** of iterating and processing the data abstract as well.  It could with worker pools, or fork join, or it could go in an order favorable to CPU cache locality, or any number of things.  You're no longer telling the JVM exactly how to do something you are getting closer to telling it what to do and letting it figure out how.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of get the idea now. The reason I asked this question was that most of the articles focused on this lazy evaluation and how streams was providing these intermediate methods which were lazy. But they never mentioned why it is better than the typical imperative for loops.

Comment: @AgentX lazy evaluation is boiler-room stuff. It's selling from features rather than selling from what the practitioner is freed to do. Instead of selling fire flowers we have to focus on selling Mario's ability to throw fireballs. Easy to forget ;)